# "give my money back" or "give me my money back"

Tags: word-usage

could you help me understand this?

source : ["common mistakes at CAE"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521603773)

page 9, question 5

"Are these sentences right or wrong? Correct those which are wrong."

4 - "I complained about the service and they agreed to have my money back"

==============

So I thought the answer should be " ... and they agreed to **give** my money back"

but the answer key says : "... and they agreed to **give me** my money back"

_

I tried searching on the web, but both appears to be right.
When there's no **back** , the subject that will receive the money is explicit

so... are both right? should I "always" use the structure **"give + subject + object"** or "**"give + object + 'to' subject"** ?

Thanks a lot and sorry any mistakes.

Comment: No, you can say you are thankful and want to *give back* or *give back to the community*.

Answer (score 3):

The phrasal verb "to give back" can be constructed in two ways. ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/give-back#giveback3_e))

> a] **give somebody something  back**
> b] **give something  back (to somebody)**

The parentheses in the second construction mean that the indirect object is not necessary; therefore the following are correct;

- Give me my money back.
- Give my money back.

The second form is not often used; however, it is correct and it can be verified in the books that it is in use ([comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=give+my+money+back%2Cgive+me+my+money+back&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgive%20my%20money%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20me%20my%20money%20back%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgive%20my%20money%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20me%20my%20money%20back%3B%2Cc0), [occurrences of "give my money back"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22give%20my%20money%20back%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)).

According to this information, both possibilities are correct.

Comment: so the question of the book should have both answers? 

4 - "I complained about the service and they agreed to have my money back"
both are right then?

" ... and they agreed to give my money back"

"... and they agreed to give me my money back"

***considering that the CAE uses British English most of the time

Comment: @Votric "To have my money back" is not correct, I believe; it should be "to **let** ***me*** have my money back". I haven't paid attention to the question of possible differences between BrE and AmE, but the fact that in the OALD no special mention (such as "North American)" is found beside the entries, is an assurance that the information is true for both variants of the language.

Comment: [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/give-back) has a clear example of the non-IO usage: 'The company had to give back all the money customers had paid.'

Comment: The clause "they agreed to give my money back" is grammatical. The clause "they agreed to give me my money back" is grammatical. The clause "they agreed to have my money back" is also grammatical, **but** it doesn't mean they'll give it back but they'll accept it back, like from you, which may not make sense in coordination with the prior clause "I complained about the service," or it would make more sense if the coordinating conjunction were "but," but there's nothing ungrammatical about the clause "they agreed to have my money back," though "take" instead of "have" would be more common.

Comment: Any reason to why the answer key says that **"I complained about the service and they agreed to give me my money back"** is the correct answer? or it is just a mistake of the book?

Comment: @Votric I'd say it is a mistake, due, possibly, to the fact that in the spoken language the shortened form could be even less frequent than what is shown on the ngram, the frequency given by this information taking into account only the written material. Of course, it is sometimes the case that written material reflects the spoken language, particularly in those cases of utterances that are central in this latter aspect of the language.

Comment: I would say that "Give my money back" is more likely to be used when someone has taken your physical cash and you want them to return the actual coins and notes. In that case it is short for "give my money back _to me_". In the case of a transaction you wish to cancel you don't care about the same units being returned, you just want the other party to give you an equivalent amount, you might have given them ten £10 notes for example but you would be happy to have five £20 notes returned. If you had paid by card or bank transfer you want your account crediting with the same amount.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Right, it would have been more thoughtful on my part to mention that the correctness had to do with sense only, not grammar.

Comment: I think I found the answer.
Based in the book "common mistakes at CAE" the verb "give" is a transitive verb that always needs an direct object (to whom) , so in formal English it appears that the direct object is requirement. If you give, you give someone something always...
in informal context or just spoken English, this is not the case 

from now on, i will always use "give someone something" in any exam or formal context

what you guys think?

Comment: @Votric  For the common meaning of "to give", this is what you have to do, always mention an object (we are not talking about the phrasal verb "to give back" now); however there is a specialization of the meaning, "to pay money to a charity, etc.", which allows the possibility of no object (examples  from OALD: "We need your help—please give generously. - They both gave generously to charity.).